# Включить curl. Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

Не работает curl. Ubuntu, apache2, php5.
В phpinfo() есть только 2 упоминания 'curl'.
1 - Additional .ini files parsed, значение - /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini.
2 - в таблице "Module Authors" строка "cUrl" со значением "Sterling Hughes"

В php.ini и в /etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini и в /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini - extension установлен абсолютный путь к curl.so. Сама библиотека curl.so на месте, проверял. В чем может быть проблема???

Comment: пакет `php5-curl` установлен?

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка, потому что отсюда это абсолютно неочевидно.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev php5-curl`
`Уже установлена самая новая версия php5-curl.
Уже установлена самая новая версия curl.
Уже установлена самая новая версия libcurl3.
Уже установлена самая новая версия libcurl4-openssl-dev.`
В php скрипте вызываю curl_init(). Выдает ошибку - "Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()..."

Comment: @СергейДеревянко (если это был ответ мне, то имело смысл доабвить @alexanderbarakin, чтобы я получил уведомление). если пакет стоит, тогда, действительно, как уже попросил @Etki, напишите сообщение об ошибке, которое появляется в логах при попытке обращения к `curl` из php.

Comment: @Etki Вот строка из лога "[Mon Jun 08 23:06:57.357035 2015] [:error] [pid 3710] [client 127.0.0.1:35743] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in"

Comment: @СергейДеревянко, *apache* перезапускали после установки `php5-curl`?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  да, даже машину перезапустил...

Comment: @СергейДеревянко, ну тогда по порядку. `/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini` — это, обычно, симлинк на файл `/etc/php5/mods-available/curl.ini`. посмотрел на тестовой машине: в этом файле не указан абсолютный путь. т.е. раскомментированная строка выглядит как `extension=curl.so`. попробуйте привести файл к этому виду и перезапустите *apache*.

Comment: @СергейДеревянко, контрольный вопрос: пакеты *apache2*, *php5*, *libapache2-mod-php5*, *php5-curl* — они все из официального репозитория дистрибутива или из каких-нибудь «левых» репозиториев?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Да, там так и было, это я уже поменял на абсолютный путь, вернул как было. Перезапустился... не помогло...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, все из коробки, ubuntu mate 15.04

Comment: @СергейДеревянко, тогда выясняйте, где «затык». рекомендация: включите (если отключали) «дефолтный сайт», docroot у него обычно где-нибудь в `/var/www/html`. создайте в его docroot-е php-файл с вызовом *phpinfo()* , откройте этот файл в браузере и поищите секцию про curl. если всё происходит на *localhost*-е, то так и обращайтесь: `http://localhost/file-with-phpinfo.php`

Comment: @СергейДеревянко, в выводе phpinfo должна присутствовать секция примерно [такого вида](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/images/phpinfo-curl.jpg).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin да, я так и делал, писал выше. А можно запустить apache с подробным выводом, может там что можно увидеть?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нет у меня этой таблицы...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin покажи мне пожалуйста секцию curl  в php.ini

Comment: @СергейДеревянко, если речь про `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`, то секция `[curl]` в нём пустая, как и должно быть по умолчанию.